# Wordpress CSS theme modification

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to modify the width of the sidebar given in this theme:
http://ericulous.com/2008/09/09/wp-theme-google-chrome/

After modifying the obvious:

```
/* Sidebar */
.sidebar {
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 25px;
width: 308px;
}
```

to reflect:

```
/* Sidebar */
.sidebar {
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 25px;
width: 100px;
}
```

The page does not look right. To help you visualize the screen, here is a screenshot, and pastebin of style.css.

http://img64.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110404at253.png/

http://pastebin.com/4ZRa1RVJ

Comment: typo, the new sidebar def is this:
    width: 100px;

Comment: You can edit question directly. And you could post how it looks without modification. I'm not clear what you want.

Comment: Ivan, thank you... i've modified the question.  I am trying to shrink the sidebar so it fits nicely around the adsense, not be so wide

Comment: HTML would be nice, at least to know what the HTML structure is about. Obviously, downloading unmodified theme is too much here :)

Comment: @Clustermagnet: Those image Google ads only seem to come in `120 x 600` or `160 x 600` (https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en/AdFormats.html), which means it's too big for the sidebar and I suspect you're using an inner `<div class="sidebarbox">` too which adds +30px in padding.

Comment: Sure, one more: http://pastebin.com/JENMWpte

Comment: I am running 120x600 pix skyscraper now... still nothing... i would love to shrink that sidebox somehow... not able to do it via css  for some reason... could it be the header thats making it so wide?

Comment: This question is extremely difficult to answer without a live example. Given a live example, we could probably figure it out pretty fast using Firebug to dynamically edit the css within the page.

Comment: http://skygames.us
  You will see what the sidebar looks like

Comment: ideally, it should be flush to the right...

Comment: figured it out, its the images pushing the sidebar, http://skygames.us/wp-content/themes/gchrome/images/sidebartop.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar contains images called sidebartop.gif and sidebarbottom.gif. These are 308 pixels wide still. You need to shrink them down so that the div can collapse small enough for your content.